# What does "Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component" mean?

Tags: javascript, html, react-router, reactjs

So I have one root component and two child components. I have trying to get one child to call a method that is up in in the root component and update the state up in the root component, and pass the updated down to the other component, but I am getting the following error.

What could be the issue?

`warning.js?8a56:36 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the firstChild component.`

**Here is the code:**

**firstChild.js**

```
export default class firstChild extends React.Component {    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      nameText: '',
    }
  }

  nameChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      nameText: event.target.value,
    })
  }

  submitClick() {
    var nameText = this.state.nameText;
    
    this.props.saveName(nameText)
    this.setState({nameText: ''});
  }

  render() {
    var st = this.state;
    var pr = this.props;

    return (

    <input
      placeholder='Enter Name'
      onChange={this.nameChange.bind(this)}
      value={this.state.nameText}
    />

    <button
      onClick={this.submitClick.bind(this)}
    />
```

And in root component, **App.js**:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      submitSuccess: false
    }
  }

  saveName(nameText) {
      this.setState({submitSuccess: true});
  }

  render() {

    var props = {};
    props.submitSuccess = this.state.submitSuccess;

    return (
      <div>
          <firstChild
            saveName={this.saveName.bind(this)}
          />

        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
          return React.cloneElement(child, props);
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And my **secondChild.js**:

```
export default class secondChild extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    submitSuccess: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.submitSuccess}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You should place back the relevant code which corresponds to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisrt, rename all your React components as Camel Case like this.

```
class firstChild ... --> class FristChild
<fristChild> --> <FristChild>
```

Second, in your `FirstChild` render method, you should wrap your elements into an enclosing tag like this:

```
class FirstChild extends Component {
render(){
   return (
      <div>
        <input ... />
        <button ... />
      </div>
   )
}
}
```

Third, when you use `cloneElement` upon `this.props.children`, you should use `Proptypes.<type>` in your `secondChildren` instead of `Propstypes.<type>.isRequired`. Check it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4494#issuecomment-125068868) to see why.

```
class SecondChild extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      submitSuccess: React.PropTypes.bool, // remove isRequired
    }
}
```

Regardless all above, I have tested your code and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle function in order to check when the component is unmounted.

You can also use a flag to signal that the component is unmounted before setting the state:

```
saveName(nameText) {
    if (!this.isUnmounted){
        this.setState({submitSuccess: true});
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.isUnmounted = true;
}
```

Comment: sorry but could you explain why I should be doing what you suggested? Trying to learn. Why should component be unmounted before setting the state?

Comment: My guess is that one of the events happens before the component is mounted. Probably the changeName on FirstChild.